# Unable to select rows containing multiple values in mysqli

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE TABLE  `product` (
  `productId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `productName` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `hashTags` varchar(255) 
.......
)
```

I have multiple values in `hashTags` column in a single cell like 11,12,13,14

```
SELECT  hashTags  FROM `product` WHERE  hashTags in (11,14);
```

when i try this query it selects only the column which first value is true with the query for its corresponding cell so how do i proceed ?

```
+------------+
| hashTags   |
+------------+
| 11,14,12,13|
+------------+
| 13,14,15   |
+------------+
```

i want to write query which selects rows containing `14` as its `hashTag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, storing multiple values in a column is BAD! See [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Try using the `like` operator:

```
SELECT  hashTags  
FROM `product` 
WHERE hashTags like '%,14,%' 
   or hashTags like '%,14' 
   or hashTags like '14,%' 
   or hashTags like '14'.
```

However this isn't the best way to maintain your data, its too much theory to describe here but the idea is the following:

Create an addition `HashTag(hashTagId, productId)` table that stores a tag for a specific product, using your example and assuming your product has ID 1, the following rows stores the same information you have in your column hashTags.

```
HashTags
--------
11  |  1
12  |  1
13  |  1
14  |  1
```

Now, to query a particular product with tags 11 and 14 use a query like:

```
SELECT productId, 
       productName, ... 
FROM Product, 
     HashTags 
WHERE HashTag.productId = Product.productId 
  AND HashTag.hashTagId = 14 
   OR hashTagId = 13.
```

Actually the query could be more complex to ensure a product has both hash tags but this is basic idea. See the link in the first line.